# spotify crash on elementary OS

Tags: linux, spotify, elementary-os

when I try to start spotify it opens a black window with spotify, and shuts straight down. Running it from Terminal I get following error:

FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(445)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

Any tips on how to fix this, or knowladge to what is the orgin of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `--no-zygote` when launching

```sh
spotify --no-zygote
```

If you're still getting black screen then try disabling gpu rendering, for that just add the following flags

```sh
spotify --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
```

If any of the case works. Then you can simply apply these flags on the `.desktop` file of the application. it is usually located at `/usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop`